# Implementing custom LinkedArrayList with extending AbstractList

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, linked-list

#### Problem Definition

- I need a collection which has nodes and each node has a constant size partially filled array. Each array may contain different size as long as smaller than previously defined constant size. There will be list of these nodes.

**For example :**

- When an element is needed to be added to the list , list adds an element at the first appropriate node which is not full. If i continuously **add(1)** , **add(2)** , **add(3)** , **add(4)** , **add(1)** **,** list will be demonstrated like this :
- Suppose `DEFAULT_NODE_CAPACITY = 3`

  - **node-0** -> "123"
  - **node-1** -> "41"

---

- When an element is needed to be removed from the list , list removes an element from the first appropriate node which contains and matched with given element. If i **remove(1)** from the list , list will be demonstrated like this :

  - **node-0** -> "23"
  - **node-1** -> "41"

---

#### What did I try ?

- I have considered the using inner class which is static one , because node class should not access the fields and methods of outher class. All types must have been generic so I put the generic key value that is identical for each constructor.
- Critical point was that I had to use AbstractList class in my custom collection.At this point I really confuse about what structure that i will be use for invocating node class which has partially fixed array.

---

#### Questions

- How can I override AbstractList methods which conform my node inner class . When I read the [Java API Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#AbstractList()) , for creating modifiable i just need to override

  - **get()**
  - **set()**
  - **remove()**
  - **add()**
  - **size()**
    at this point , how can i override all of them efficiently by conforming my problem definition ?
- What data type should I use for invocating `Node<E>` ? and How can implement it ?

---

#### How did I implement ?

```java
package edu.gtu.util;

import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class LinkedArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E> , Collection<E>, Iterable<E> {

    public static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
    public static final int CONSTANT_NODE_CAPACITY = 3;

    /* Is that wrong ? , how to be conformed to AbstractList ? */
    private Node<E>[] listOfNode = null;
    /*---------------------------------------------------------*/

    private int size;

    private static class Node<E> {

        private Object[] data;
        private Node<E> next = null;
        private Node<E> previous = null;

        private Node( Object[] data , Node<E> next , Node<E> previous ) {

            setData(data);
            setNext(next);
            setPrevious(previous);

        }

        private Node( Object[] data ) {
            this( data , null , null );
        }

        private void setData( Object[] data ) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        private void setNext( Node<E> next ) {
            this.next = next;
        }
        private void setPrevious( Node<E> previous ) {
            this.previous = previous;
        }

        private Object[] getData() {
            return data;
        }
        private Node<E> getNext() {
            return next;
        }
        private Node<E> getPrevious() {
            return previous;
        }

    }


    private void setSize( int size ) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public LinkedArrayList() {
        super();
    }

    public LinkedArrayList( int size ) {
        super();

        setSize( size );
        listOfNode = (Node<E>[]) new Object[size()];
    }

    public LinkedArrayList(Collection<E> collection ) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public E get( int i ) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return super.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return super.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        return super.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

}
```

Comment: Look careful. As the documentation states, you have to override `get(int)`, `set(int, E)`, `add(int, E)` and `remove(int)`, not just some `add` and `remove` methods. And overriding means filling with an actual implementation, not just doing a `super` call that would act as if the method has never been overridden. The implementation is up to you, that's your task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add a field to `Node` that tells you how many data items are stored in that node.

Then:

- `size` has to iterate over the nodes and compute the sum of the sizes of the nodes. Or you can maintain a separate size, and update it with every add and remove.
- `add` has to find the node where the item can be inserted. If there's room in that node, just add it there. If that node is full, you have to create a new node.
- `remove` has to find the right node and remove the item from that node. If the node becomes empty, the node itself can be removed.
- `get` has to iterate over the nodes, keeping track of how many items it skips over, until it find the node that must contain the node.
- `set` - same as `get`, except that it replaces the item in addition to returning it

You'll find better descriptions in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrolled_linked_list
This article also suggests an important optimization for add/remove.